# "no sooner had the tree {been fallen/fallen} than..."

Tags: word-choice

> No sooner had the tree **been fallen**  than it's branches were cut off.

> No sooner had the tree **fallen** than it's branches were cut off.

Can you tell me which is right?

Comment: I think you're confusing two different verbs here. Intransitive ***to fall*** = *to drop to the ground, to collapse* is correctly used in your Past Perfect example #2. But there's also transitive ***to fell*** = *to **cause** to fall* (typically, as in *The lumberjack **fells** the tree* by chopping it down with an axe). In your "passive" construction #1 (where the "agent" who felled the tree is unspecified) the correct verb form would be *No sooner had the tree been **felled** than its branches were cut off.* But that's nothing to do with ***no sooner than***.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities that are both correct. They also assume a slight change in the indication of the possessive: in this case, it should be *its*, not *it's*.

> ✔ No sooner had the tree **fallen** than its branches were cut off.
>   ✔ No sooner had the tree **been** ***felled*** than its branches were cut off.

*Fallen* is an intransitive verb, and it's being used as such in the first sentence.

But in the second sentence, it's talking about a tree being *caused* to fall by something else. So, it requires a transitive verb in the passive voice.

Which you want to use depends on where you want to put the emphasis and what you're trying to describe. Did the tree fall down on its own, or was it cut down by somebody? (Or, if it was cut down by somebody, is that important?)